# Dependency Injection for objects with different number of parameters in Java

Tags: java, constructor, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I have to make an implementation in which I have a super class A and two classes B and C both extending A, but both B and C have constructor with different number of parameters.
B has a constructor with 2 parameters and C has a constructor with 1 parameter. 
Is there a way I can create the objects dynamically using Dependency injection.
Right now I am passing null for second parameter by creating a dummy constructor in C. I do not want to use this approach though. So is there a better way to handle this.

Right now I am using factory pattern to create the class, but want to be able to move it to Dependency Injection. Following is the current code I have

```
        public A getA(String type, String name, String extra)
            throws InvalidSubscriberTypeException {
        if (Types.B.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(type.toUpperCase())) {
            return new B(name);
        } else if (Types.C.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                type.toUpperCase())) {
            return new C(name,extra);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidSubscriberTypeException(
                    "Please select a valid subscriber - B or C");
        }
    }
```

and then I call it the following way

```
TypeFacotry.getType("B", "Bill", null) 
TypeFacotry.getType("C", "Bill", "Deck") 

If someone can suggest a DI implementation for the same
```

Comment: You need to tell your dependency injection framework what to pass as parameters to the constructors. I don't see how the fact that the extend a common class and have a different number of parameters changes anything. If only you showed us code, told us what you use as dependency injection framework, and showed us how you create instances of B and C, we could provide better help.

Comment: Dependency injection won't allow you to dynamically create objects by passing parameters. You'll need code equivalent as above, even with DI.

Comment: So you mean I would have to pass a null or something else as done above. Also, in case if I still remain with the same implementation, is there a better way to handle such a scenario.

Comment: No, I mean that you'll still need one or several factory methods. I would refector this method as two methods: `createB(String name)`, and `createC(String name, String extra)`.

Comment: Oh, so you mean just on the basis of difference in the number of parameters I decide which object to return

Comment: No. Based on the method called. `createA()` create As. `createB()` create Bs.